# How do I unnest an array inside a function?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

```
create or replace function pd.check(
    interval_ text[]) 

returns void as

$BODY$
BEGIN

EXECUTE '
drop table if exists check_;
create temp table check_ 
as
(
    select unnest(' || interval_ || ')
) ;
';
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL volatile;
```

I am running it as

```
select pd.check(ARRAY['2','3','4']);
```

It gives me an error :

> operator is not unique: unknown || text[]
>
> HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Your Postgres version is **essential** to any such question. Remember to always provide it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming current Postgres 9.6, your function would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pd.check(interval_ text[]) 
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE '
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pg_temp.check_;
      CREATE TEMP TABLE check_  AS
      SELECT unnest($1)'
   USING $1;                                -- pass as value
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Notes

- You *could* concatenate the parameter value as string, but then you need an explicit type cast (since concatenating an *untyped string literal* and `text[]`  is ambiguous to Postgres, it might produce `text` or `text[]`, hence the error!) and escape special characters to make it work. `quote_literal()` does both: `quote_literal(interval_)`. Still, ***don't***.
  Instead, pass the parameter as ***value***, not as string. That's faster and safer and avoids any such error as you show.
  Note that `$1` in the command string refers to the first expression provided by the `USING` clause, not to the function parameter. The 2nd instance of `$1` actually refers to the function parameter (different scope!).
- **Note**, that this superior way of passing values to DML statements works here because it's part of the included `SELECT` statement, but not for other utility commands. Details:

  - [“ERROR: there is no parameter $1” in “EXECUTE .. USING ..;” statement in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121453/error-there-is-no-parameter-1-in-execute-using-statement-in-plpgsql/121549#121549)
- `drop table check_;` in a function is ***dangerous***. Obviously you want to target the temporary table. But if that should not exist, the next available table of the same name in the [search_path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777) would be dropped. Potentially catastrophic damage. To target the temp table and no other, schema-qualify with the pseudo-name `pg_temp`.
- [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html) does not require parentheses around a following `SELECT` command.
- `VOLATILE`  is the default (and correct for this function), I omitted the noise.

In this particular case you would not need dynamic SQL. See [@klin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44709276/939860). But `EXECUTE` is still a good choice for queries that have nothing to gain from plan caching.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a dynamic SQL (execute):

```
create or replace function pd.check(interval_ text[]) 
returns void as
$body$
begin
    drop table if exists check_;
    create temp table check_
    as select unnest(interval_);
end;
$body$
language plpgsql volatile;
```

Test:

```
select pd.check(array['2','3','4']);
select * from check_;

 unnest 
--------
 2
 3
 4
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the other answer, but you really shouldn't be using RETURNS VOID; you should be returning a set from the function itself.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pd.check(
  intervals_ TEXT[] )
RETURNS TABLE ( pd_interval TEXT )
$f$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT UNNEST(intervals_);
END;
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

postgres=# select * from pd_check(ARRAY['1','2','3']);
 pd_interval 
-------------
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```

Other changes I made:

1. You shouldn't name a column after a different data type than the column itself, hence changing interval_ to intervals_.
2. The function is actually IMMUTABLE, not VOLATILE, as-is.

Comment: Then the function makes no sense because you can use `select * from unnest(array[...])` as well. The OP for some reason just want to have given numbers in a temporary table to use it elsewhere.

Comment: Well, it's up to the OP in what s/he actually wants.  Possibly OP wants to put them in a temp table, but possibly OP was unaware that RETURNS TABLE existed.  And I'm assuming that the function wrapper is because s/he actually wants to do something more complicated than just an unnest.